# bibtex acm style: potentially double period if the year is missing

Tags: bibtex, acm

Running `latex` and `bibtex` in a loop on

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mwe.bib}
@article{Types,
  author={Abra K. Dabra},
  title={Types in Programming: {Bool}, {Char}, {Int}},
  journal={Int. J. Comp.},
  OPTyear=2000
}
\end{filecontents}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\cite{Types}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

yields

> [1]
>
> **References**
>
> [1] Dᴀʙʀᴀ, A. K. Types in programming: Bool, Char, Int. *Int. J. Comp.*.

The last but one period is italic, and the last one is upright. This is not well visible. Any way to repair the `acm` style to drop the final full stop if the year is missing? The class is old, from 1986 with last corrections in 2010, so there might be a standard fix.

Comment: What's your reason for *wanting* to omit the `year` field when a value for this field exists?

Comment: @Mico Sometimes the value for `year` is unknown. Sometimes you have to save space. Sometimes there is no year but a range of years, and you may decide it's best to drop the range.

Comment: For the `acm` style, the `year` field is *required* for entries of type `@article`. For entries of type `@article`, there's simply no way that the publication year could be "unknown". If you have to save space, choose a different bibliography style than `acm`. What's stopping you from entering the year range into the `year` field? The point of providing a bibliography is to give readers sufficient information to enable them to find the entries themselves; how can omitting a year range help your readers find the article in question?

Comment: @Mico Why are you always so keen on avoiding the question? Let's say that the ACM style is what your publisher expects, and you need to save space to get into the page limits.

Comment: To repeat an earlier point: The purpose of providing a bibliography is to help your readers find the references, should they feel so inclined. Omitting a year field in the name of "saving space" is to do your readers a disservice.

Comment: @AlMa1r If your publisher expects acm style, chances are your publisher also expects a year. Publishers expect certain bib styles, because that's what they want the bibliographies to look like.

Comment: After the author name, the year is usually the second most important information to actually find an article. If you really must remove information to safe space, remove something else. (and be prepared that your publisher might decline a submission which fails to use the style they require)

Comment: @Mico Regarding your “do your readers a disservice”: As you probably very well know, academia is a hard business, and you sometimes don't have any margin whatsoever to please (or not please) the reader with the date of the works of someone else, but you *first* have to struggle a lot to get into formal limitations, and then the deadline expires, say, in 2 minutes. I do wish it were different, but not everyone has a chance to act as DEK with respect to the bibliography.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I never heard of an an article being declined because of year omitted in the bibliography. Sure the reviewers may complain but running over the limits would be the first issue they'd complain about (and only then, if they notice it, a date of some reference).

Answer (score 1):

The full stop at the end of the entry is (like most other full stops in the bibliography) produced by `add.period$`.

According to [TameTheBeast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) `add.period$`

> adds a period at the end of string S, except if S already ends with a period, or an exclamation or question mark (after removing right braces);

But unfortunately, `acm` prints the `journal` with the function `emphasizeic`, which is defined as

```
FUNCTION {emphasizeic}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "\/}" * }
  if$
}
```

So we have `{\em Int. J. Comp.\/}` on the stack, which doesn't end with a full stop even after removing any right braces. This means that `add.period$` adds another full stop.

Fortunately, there has been a solution for this for about thirty years now: Use `\emph{...}` instead of `{\em ...}`.

So I would modify a copy of `acm.bst` to replace all instances of something like

```
"{\em " ... * "\/}"
```

or

```
"{\em " ... * "}"
```

with something like

```
"\emph{" ... * "}"
```

There is only one such instance that matters for this example, namely the one in `emphasizeic`, but while we're at it, we may as well change the others. Here is the `diff` between the original `acm.bst` and `acm-emph.bst`

```
--- acm.bst 2010-12-09 04:09:07.000000000 +0100
+++ acm-emph.bst    2024-02-25 09:45:26.932302800 +0100
@@ -1,3 +1,7 @@
+%%%% ACM with \emph{...} instead of {\em ...}
+%%%% 2024-02-25 MW
+%%%% for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/710339/35864
+%%%% replace instances of "{\em " ... * "\/}" with "\emph{" ... * "}"
 % Copyright (C) 1986, 1988, 2010 Howard Trickey and Oren Patashnik.
 % Unlimited copying and redistribution of this file are permitted as long as
 % it is unmodified.  Modifications (and redistribution of modified versions)
@@ -167,14 +171,14 @@
 FUNCTION {emphasize}
 { duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
-    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
+    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
 }
 
 FUNCTION {emphasizeic}
 { duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
-    { "{\em " swap$ * "\/}" * }
+    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
 }
 
@@ -546,7 +550,7 @@
           warning$
           ""
         }
-        { "In {\em " journal * "\/}" * }
+        { "In \emph{" journal * "}" * }
       if$
     }
     { "In " key * }
@@ -589,7 +593,7 @@
               crossref * warning$
               "" *
             }
-            { "{\em " * series * "\/}" * }
+            { "\emph{" * series * "}" * }
           if$
         }
         { key * }
@@ -610,7 +614,7 @@
               crossref * warning$
               ""
             }
-            { "In {\em " booktitle * "\/}" * }
+            { "In \emph{" booktitle * "}" * }
           if$
         }
         { "In " key * }
```

With `acm-emph.bst`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Types,
  author={Abra K. Dabra},
  title={Types in Programming: {Bool}, {Char}, {Int}},
  journal={Int. J. Comp.},
  OPTyear=2000,
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{Types}
\bibliographystyle{acm-emph}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: [1] Dabra, A. K. Types in programming: Bool, Char, Int. Int. J. Comp.]

Comment: Thx! Off-topic: I get a bigger gap between “Int.” and “*Int.*” than on your output.